I got "MongoInvalidArgumentError: Argument "pipeline" must be an array of aggregation stages" in node red
Please help me I new at node-red and I try to use Aggregate pipeline to query data in mongoDB by using node-red with mongodb4 driver. I got "MongoInvalidArgumentError: Argument "pipeline" must be an array of aggregation stages" for long time firstly I use mongodb3 and it still get same error.
This is my msg.payload setup before sending to mongodb4.
if (typeof msg.payload !== 'object') {
  msg.payload = {};
}


msg.payload.pipeline = [
    {
      "$match": {
        [`pallete.${msg.req.query.id}`]: { "$exists": true }
      }
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        "pallete": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$pallete",
            "as": "item",
            "cond": { "$gt": [{ "$type": `$$item.${msg.req.query.id}` }, "missing"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
];

return msg;

This is mongodb4 set up.
This is msg.payload before sending to mongodb4
This is error from catch error that I set.
I try to use aggregate pipeline in mongodb4 node-red to make them query and show only match data in my collection but I still got this error for two days.
